# How to configure Jacoco with SonarQube and Maven in Jenkins

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, sonarqube, maven-3, jacoco

I Am trying to enable Sonarqube code coverage scan. I work on a Maven project in Eclipse and have already setup a successful Jenkins-build including Sonar-scan.

I already succeeded in using Jacoco locally; I added the Jacoco plugin to the pom.xml and executed `jacoco:prepare-agent test jacoco:report` via `Run As-> Maven build...`. After that call the html reports were located in `target\site\jacoco` and they seem to be correct.

Now I need to make it work in Jenkins but I don't know how to correctly configure the build. Currently the maven goal `clean package -fae` and an `Invoke Standalone Sonar Analysis` build step are executed.
 I found out that `sonar.jacoco.reportPath` needs do be set, but I don't know where to set it or where to call the `jacoco:report` target. Also I am unsure whether I need to add the jacoco plugin to jenkins as well, or if it is sufficient to do so in the maven project.

Any help is much appreciated, also please let me know if there is anything I can do to improve my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it work. In case someone has similar issues I am posting my solution here:

In Jenkins the properties sonar.junit.reportsPath and sonar.jacoco.reportPath need to be configured. No additional goals have to be executed in Jenkins.

In the projects pom.xml one needs to specify

```
    <properties>
       <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.7.4.201502262128</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>(,0.7.4.201502262128]</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The goal `prepare-agent` has to be executed, but it first generates a

> Resource Path Location Type Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration

To resolve that, the  `pluginManagement` block is needed, since it ignores the upcoming issues. Here it is evident to use `versionRange` and not just `version`, also this specific version is required, later versions are not working here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to install and configure jacoco plugin in jenkins.

Foolow this link which explains it

https://dzone.com/articles/jacoco-jenkins-plugin

Comment: Thanks, but I can not configure Jenkins.  But I found out, that one does not have to install the plugin, it can be configured via Maven

Comment: In order to report and status you need install and configure plugin, try once to know the results if you want

Comment: I do not have the necessary rights to configure Jenkins